# In Unity, how to setup leaderboard with multiple keys, name, dob, and so on, and ranked by score?

Tags: database, unity-game-engine, leaderboard

I want to achieve the following leaderboard:

- 1: Player 1, score 100, kill 4, death 2
- 2: Player 2, score 90, kill 3, death 1
- 3: Player 3, score 80, kill 2, death 0

The dataset set sorted by score.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to use GameSparks SDK.